# How to make a number line with complete labels?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I don't really understand why

- there is always no zero
- sometimes I get incomplete labels at the ends

How to make the number lines have complete labels?

## Case 1: Multiple of omega

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\Const{2*pi*10}% f = 10 Hz

\FPeval\Right{2*Const}
\FPeval\Left{0-Const}

\FPset\xTrigLabelBase{3}
\FPset\Dx{1}
\FPeval\dx{Const/xTrigLabelBase*Dx}
\FPeval\XUnit{10/(Right-Left)}

\psset
{
    yAxis=false,
    xunit=\XUnit,
    dx=\dx,
    Dx=\Dx,
    xtrigLabels,
    xtrigLabelBase=\xTrigLabelBase,
}


\def\pi{\omega}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
    \psaxes(0,0)(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Case 2: Multiple of pi

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\Const{pi}

\FPeval\Right{2*Const}
\FPeval\Left{0-Const}

\FPset\xTrigLabelBase{3}
\FPset\Dx{1}
\FPeval\dx{Const/xTrigLabelBase*Dx}
\FPeval\XUnit{10/(Right-Left)}

\psset
{
    yAxis=false,
    xunit=\XUnit,
    dx=\dx,
    Dx=\Dx,
    xtrigLabels,
    xtrigLabelBase=\xTrigLabelBase,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
    \psaxes(0,0)(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Case 3: Multiple of square root of 2

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\Const{root(2,2)}

\FPeval\Right{2*Const}
\FPeval\Left{0-Const}

\FPset\xTrigLabelBase{3}
\FPset\Dx{1}
\FPeval\dx{Const/xTrigLabelBase*Dx}
\FPeval\XUnit{10/(Right-Left)}

\psset
{
    yAxis=false,
    xunit=\XUnit,
    dx=\dx,
    Dx=\Dx,
    xtrigLabels,
    xtrigLabelBase=\xTrigLabelBase,
}


\def\pi{\sqrt2}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
    \psaxes(0,0)(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Case 4: Multiple of 90 degrees

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\Const{pi}

\FPeval\Right{2*Const}
\FPeval\Left{0-Const}

\FPset\xTrigLabelBase{180}
\FPset\Dx{90}
\FPeval\dx{Const/xTrigLabelBase*Dx}
\FPeval\XUnit{10/(Right-Left)}

\psset
{
    yAxis=false,
    xunit=\XUnit,
    dx=\dx,
    Dx=\Dx,
    xlabelFactor={}^\circ,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
    \psaxes(0,0)(\Left,-12pt)(\Right,12pt)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

The problem still exists even though I use the latest version provided by Herbert.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\psset{yAxis=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,0)(13,8)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=cyan!50](!Pi 0)(!Pi 8)
\rput(0,1){%
    \psaxes(0,0)(-7,-12pt)(13,12pt)%
}
\rput(0,3){%
    \def\pi{\sqrt{17}}%
    \psaxes[xtrigLabels,xtrigLabelBase=3,dx=\pscalculate{sqrt(17)/3}](0,0)(-\pscalculate{sqrt(17)},-12pt)(\pscalculate{2*sqrt(17)},12pt)%
}
\rput(0,5){%
    \psaxes[xtrigLabels,xtrigLabelBase=3,dx=\pscalculate{pi/3}](0,0)(-\psPi,-12pt)(\psPiFour,12pt)%
}
\rput(0,7){%
    \psaxes[xlabelFactor={}^\circ,dx=\pscalculate{pi/2},Dx=90](0,0)(-\psPi,-12pt)(\psPiFour,12pt)%
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new `pst-plot.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pst-plot/

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\psset{yAxis=false,xtrigLabels,xtrigLabelBase=3}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-5mm)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\def\pi{\omega}% Hold it local
\psaxes[dx=\pstRadUnit,Ox=-3](-\psPi,-12pt)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-5mm)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\psaxes[dx=\pstRadUnit,Ox=-3](-\psPi,-12pt)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-5mm)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\def\pi{\sqrt2}% Hold it local
\psaxes[dx=\pstRadUnit,Ox=-3](-\psPi,-12pt)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip
\psset{trigLabels=false}
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-5mm)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\psaxes[dx=\pscalculate{3.14/2},Dx=90,Ox=-180](-\psPi,-12pt)(\psPiTwo,12pt)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\psset{yAxis=false}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-7,0)(13,8)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=cyan!50](!Pi 0)(!Pi 8)
\rput(0,1){\psaxes[Ox=-7](-7,-5mm)(13,12pt)}

\rput(0,3){%
  \def\pi{\sqrt{17}}%
  \psaxes[xtrigLabels,xtrigLabelBase=3,dx=\pscalculate{sqrt(17)/3},Ox=-3]%
      (-\pscalculate{sqrt(17)},0)(\pscalculate{2*sqrt(17)+0.01},0)%
    }
    \rput(0,5){%
        \psaxes[xtrigLabels,xtrigLabelBase=3,dx=\pscalculate{pi/3}](0,0)(-\psPi,-12pt)(\psPiFour,12pt)%
    }
  \rput(0,7){%
    \psaxes[xlabelFactor={}^\circ,dx=\pscalculate{pi/2},
      Dx=90,Ox=-180](-\psPi,-5mm)(12.58,12pt)%
  }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should use the `Ox=...` optional argument! See extended answer

Comment: feel free to rewrite the macro ...